# Why I can't throw an exception in child class before calling super()?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, first is a parent class, second is a child class.
In the child class I want to check a parameter in its constructor before calling super() because the parameter in the constructor isn't linked with the parent class.
If the check fails, I'll throw an exception.
I got this error message: "Call to 'super()' must be first statement in constructor body".
Why I can't do that? Is it possible?
I don't want to initialize the parent class because the child class isn't be initialized, it throw an exception in its constructor.

Comment: How about `super(validationMethod(parameter))`?

Comment: You can also simply do the validation after the call to the super constructor. It will still prevent the object from being successfully instantiated.

Comment: Hm, that sounds interesting

Comment: I think it'll be useful for me

Comment: But my parent class don't need this parameter, this parameter uses in only child class

Answer (score 1):

This is a long-time limitation of Java. The (well-intentioned) restriction that you have to call `super` *first thing* in the constructor causes problems like these frequently.

As mentioned in the comments, you can call other functions in the *arguments* of the `super` call which will be evaluated first, so you can get around this problem with a `static` helper function

```
public Foobar(int argument) {
  super(validateArgument(argument));
  // ...
}

private static int validateArgument(int argument) {
  if (argument >= 0) {
    return argument;
  } else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Arguments to Foobars can't be negative!");
  }
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively a static factory method, `Foobar.create(123)`, with a private constructor. Let the factory method validate, and leave the constructor to assume the values are pre-validated.

Comment: Factory sounds interesting, but the factory changes the logic of objects creations

Answer (score 1):

The call to `super` must be the first statement in a constructor. I believe this restriction was enforced because it was deemed less prone to bugs with regards to uninitialized values. e.g.

```
class Super {
    protected String foo;
    protected String bar;

    Super(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = "bar";
    }
}

class Child extends Super {
    Child() {
        // not valid java. Foo is not initialized yet 
        if (foo.length() == 1) { throw new RuntimeException(); }

        // perhaps more insidious, since bar is not passed to super
        System.out.println(this.bar);
        super("foo");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know it, I want to try to do my checks before calling super() because the parent class don't use my parameters, they use only in the child class

Comment: @DavidBlbulyan You asked "*Why I can't do that? Is it possible?*" I was answering those questions.